# Display text in the view with a delay - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I need to display some text in the view, and I also need to wait for the data to arrive from the server. So I would like to introduce a timeout for this (I know it's not the best idea, but I would like to test it). At this moment, inside the `<td>` there is nothing displayed because the data has not arrived from the server.

View:

```
<td ng-repeat="field in fields">
    myCtrl.getItem(item, field)
</td>
```

Controller:

```
$timeout(function() {
    return userServ.getName(item);  //  returns the timeout ID and not what I need
}, 3000);
```

Please advise if there is another way to display what I need in the view when I actually have the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the data that you want to display before using in ng repeat.

In your controller, loop your fields variable.

```
let items = [];

fields.forEach(field => {
    getItem(item, field).then(function(response) {
        // Assume that you have your data in response.data.item
        items.push(response.data.item);
    });
});
```

Then in your view, use the `items` in your ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The thing is this is not o simple... The data is retrieved by a service method and another service method uses that data. The second method tries to use the data, but it is not arrived yet. I am working on an application written by someone else and I cannot refactor everything .

Comment: Can you please update your question and add the services to show how it was written? So that we can formulate a solution.